# How to render django form into html (not in template)

Tags: django, forms, templates

I have a template in which I have

```
<div id="form-wrapper">
    {{form}}
</div>
```

Now if the user submits (via `AJAX`) and there are errors, I want to do

`$("#form-wrapper").html(data.form);`

Basically just replace the whole form to show the errors. But when I write

`return JsonResponse({'form': form})`

in the view django tells me that my form isn't serializable. Makes sense. So my question is: how does django render forms into html? What function should I call?

Note: I know I can return just the errors instead of the whole form, but that would require more js code in the template to put each field's errors in the correct place. I want the one function that django uses when I say `{{form}}`.

Thank you!

Comment: Could you share your views.py code ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All the template does when presented with any object is call `str()` (or `unicode()`) on it. Internally, the methods that implement those on the form class simply delegate to the [`as_table()` method](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/forms/api/#as-table). So you can just call that directly:

```
return JsonResponse({'form': form.as_table()})
```

Note, though, that you might want to add other HTML, in which case a better approach might be to simply render a short template snippet, including the form, to a string - using `render_to_string` - and send that in the Json response.

Comment: That's what it looks like the code does (I even put it through a debugger to see what the template engine produces and I see a table), but on my website there's no table. Just the labels and inputs. So am I missing something? Ended up writing my own as_html method that calls _html_output, but I want to understand why that initial rendering doesn't produce a table.

Answer (score 0):

You've gotta unload the form since it's an object

```
if not form.is_valid():
    errors = form.errors  # You'll get a dict of errors
    return JsonResponse(data=errors)
```

From here use javascript to create new HTML.

Comment: Like I said, the errors aren't enough for me. I want the html of the whole form.