# Django, forward form data using email, after submitting it to database

Tags: python, html, django

im new to django so i apologize in advance.

I've successfully created a webform that submits everything successfully to a database and also successfully emails a designated adress upon form submission.

now that everything is working I would like to add the content that is being submitted into that same email that is being sent out on submit.

send_email seemingly only takes strings and render_to_string doesnt work for me on my form.

is there an easy way to get the data being submitted into a readable format and pass it into the content of the email being sent?

```py
def snippet_detail(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = SnippetForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            send_mail('Form submitted', 'test', settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER, 
            ['email@email.com'], fail_silently = False)
            return render(request, 'submittedformsuccess.html')
```

Everything here works I simply wanna replace 'test' with for example a copy of the template form.html that the user sees, but completely filled in

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30147255/how-to-render-django-form-into-html-not-in-template ?

Comment: Thank you this brought me a lot closer, the email now includes the entirety of the form in readable format, it just doesnt include the actual filled in parts. im obviously missing something.

Comment: it's been a while since I used forms but maybe this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3833403/initial-populating-on-django-forms

Comment: so:  form = SnippetForm(initial=data) perhaps to populate it

Comment: I've gotten it to work with Pauls suggestion, but for some reason it only includes the data submitted in TextFields in the email. So checkboxes and CharFields are left blank.